# Can we embed a Salesforce login component for user authentication into a Java Portal?

Tags: authentication, widget, salesforce

Is there any way we can embed a login component of Salesforce for user authentication as Identity Provider on a non-salesforce application. The business ask is just to embed the login component as a widget into a existing portal built on Java.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Salesforce as your identity provider with an OAuth flow. So you just delegate authentication to Salesforce.  See more info  [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&type=0)